# Summarizing confidence intervals when there are many levels

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics

How can I summarize the confidence intervals for several levels of factors?

This is what I got:

```
interest rate (1.280393e+01 16.1980844628); 
fico range 645-649 (-3.581231e+00  1.9591171919); 
fico range 650-654 (-4.533451e+00  3.7764777115);     
fico range 655-659 (-2.797205e+00  2.2914947096);     
fico range 660-664 (-2.822852e-01  3.1803914727);     
fico range 665-669 (-9.659140e-01  2.4864556261);     
fico range 670-674 (-1.954018e+00  1.4892769161);     
fico range 675-679 (-2.694203e+00  0.7515725574);     
fico range 680-684 (-3.457226e+00 -0.0085546990);     
fico range 685-689 (-3.965619e+00 -0.5093765443);     
fico range 690-694 (-4.283243e+00 -0.8263499212);     
fico range 695-699 (-4.808411e+00 -1.3570095978);     
fico range 700-704 (-5.564438e+00 -2.1040755402);     
fico range 705-709 (-6.290848e+00 -2.8315079720);     
fico range 710-714 (-6.422048e+00 -2.9508840053);     
fico range 715-719 (-7.563818e+00 -4.0779259228);     
fico range 720-724 (-7.744044e+00 -4.2745503539);     
fico range 725-729 (-8.117765e+00 -4.6328158788);     
fico range 730-734 (-8.919313e+00 -5.4341114666);     
fico range 735-739 (-9.447742e+00 -5.9220440264);     
fico range 740-744 (-9.497308e+00 -5.9439118677);     
fico range 745-749 (-9.437903e+00 -5.8873782684);     
fico range 750-754 (-1.001172e+01 -6.4804655589);     
fico range 755-759 (-1.017971e+01 -6.6033187178);     
fico range 760-764 (-1.000456e+01 -6.4294990859);     
fico range 765-769 (-1.063397e+01 -7.0112845774);     
fico range 770-774 (-1.171413e+01 -7.8514910920);     
fico range 775-779 (-1.051257e+01 -6.7492730448);     
fico range 780-784 (-1.121741e+01 -7.5319951164);     
fico range 785-789 (-1.081962e+01 -7.0030665863);     
fico range 790-794 (-1.121984e+01 -7.4234794495);     
fico range 795-799 (-1.138416e+01 -7.3877810394);     
fico range 800-804 (-1.103957e+01 -7.0461654289);     
fico range 805-809 (-1.204510e+01 -7.9475491304);     
fico range 810-814 (-1.105703e+01 -6.7223043818);     
fico range 815-819 (-1.204715e+01 -7.4519985436);     
fico range 820-824 (-1.183545e+01 -3.5254524137);     
fico range 830-834 (-1.393567e+01 -5.6193498315);     
loan length60 months  (3.066167e+00  3.4715640126);     
amount requested (1.330939e-04  0.0001547571);
```

As you can see fico range has a lot of levels. What is the appropriate way to report them?

Comment: sounds like homework from cousera.org Data analysis

Comment: Yeap it could be part of the assignment, but it is passed the deadline. I realized that I don't know how to report that. Can you please answer my question? Regards. Diego

Comment: What is "FICO range"?

Comment: is a factor variable based on FICO scores https://www.asbtx.com/mortgage-loans-factors.htm that has been binned ¿? in groups that include a range of 5 scores in a scale, for example 640-644; 645-649; etc

Comment: can you explain how you arrive at the range in brackets?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The ranges #### - #### were provided. Since they are not numbers, they are treated as factors during the linear regression i.e. as.factor

Comment: You should edit your question and state how you got what you got in the box. Looks like you did a linear regression. You should also state what question you are trying to answer with the regression.

Comment: Thank you RJ but I can't do that. If this course is going to be offered in the future, that mean I'll be breaking the honor code, and that's not my policy. Additionally, I believe the question is clear enough, but if it's not let me know what else do I need to explain in plain words without putting any code here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what's wrong with the way you currently present them, although I would certainly round them rather than show so many digits.

An obvious improvement would be to plot them, with a horizontal line showing the confidence interval for each factor (or level of factor), and the levels of the factor on the vertical axis.  In general, I think this is a good way to summarise confidence intervals of coefficients from regressions and the like.